# django CBV: get current user in a form

Tags: django

I need to perform a form validation in wich current user is involved. I know how to do it but using FBV approach. Could be something like:

first declare the __ init __() method:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super(MyFormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so now I can use the self.user in any validation method.

Later in a view method I could:

```
if request.POST:
    form = MyFormClass(request.user, request.POST)
```

My question: How can I do the same but using CBV:

Currently I'm using the CreateView generic, and the form_class attr:

```
class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
   model = MyModel
   form_class = MyFormClass
```

How can I instantiate MyFormClass with the current user using this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `get_form()` or `get_form_kwargs()`. If you are fuzzy about which methods to override in CBVs, a good reference is the excellent CCBV website. Here's a link to what you want from the CCBV docs:

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_form_kwargs

Comment: Overriding `get_form` is one option, but overriding `get_form_kwargs` is DRYer.

Comment: Good point, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user in the form_valid method of CreateView.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = self.request.user
    # add your validation

    return super(YourView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: The `form_valid` method is meant for handling a valid form, I don't think it's a great idea to do further validation here.